# Windows 11 "Send to" in context menu not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-11

I have a python programme to re-size images.
From File Explorer I want to use the context menu to send images to my Python programme.
I have the following script in C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\Test Resize_1000.cmd:

```
@echo off
cls
echo %1
:upload_loop
IF "%1"=="" GOTO completed
    echo %1
    PAUSE
    C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe  D:\Files\Python36\Image\Resizer_1000.py %1
    SHIFT
    GOTO upload_loop
:completed
```

This was working under Windows 10, but is failing since upgrading to Windows 11.

The Python works fine if I call it from the command prompt thus:

```
C:\>C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe  D:\Files\Python36\Image\Resizer_1000.py "D:\Files\Photos\2023 Philippines\Dora 01.jpg"
```

When I try the "Send to" option in File Explorer, Command.com opens briefly and closes before I can read any messages.

Comment: Please also use ```IF "%~1" == "" GOTO ...```. BTW, you can replace ```C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local``` with ```%LocalAppData%```. I would have to ask specifically though, why `COMMAND.COM` is opening, as opposed to `cmd.exe`?

Comment: I suppose I should also ask why you cannot simply modify `Resizer_1000.py` to loop through arguments, instead of needlessly using a batch file for it.

Comment: The directory `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo` should not contain the batch file `Test Resize_1000.cmd`. The batch file should be in the directory `D:\Files\Python36\Image` and the `SendTo` folder should contain the shortcut file `Resize 1000.lnk` with property __Target__ being `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C D:\Files\Python36\Image\Test Resize_1000.cmd` and property __Start in__ being `D:\Files\Python36\Image` and a meaningful __Comment__ and a nice __icon__ and other properties configured as you would like on `explorer.exe` running it with all file names of selected files.

Comment: The modification of the batch file as suggested by Compo is definitely necessary, but better would be a modification of the Python script to process the list of file names itself from the arguments lists with a simple loop in Python script, see for example [How to use sys.argv in Python?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-sys-argv-in-python/) Then a batch file and the usage of `cmd.exe` would be not necessary at all and the shortcut file could run directly `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe D:\Files\Python36\Image\Resizer_1000.py` to process all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED
Compo's suggestion to use `IF "%~1" == "" GOTO ....` fixed it.

The other comments are pertinent - I will implement them when I have more time.

Many thanks.